# Unable to send html form input to javascript file to console log

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take input from html form like this

```
<body>
   <div >
      <form>
         <input placeholder="Address" >
         <button >Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <script src="./utils/input.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to console log what is entered in the form input whenever the submit button is pressed.

And `utils/input.js` looks like this

```
const address= document.querySelector('form');
const search = document.querySelector('input');


address.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const location = search.value;
    console.log(location);
})
```

But in chrome developer tools I get error like this

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/utils/input.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I am unable to figure my mistake here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input.js` file is not being imported correctly on your html file (hence `not found`).
Fix the path and it'll work.

Comment: Hey, so I looked it the actual path is ../utils/input.js but even with this it doesn't work but when I shift input.js to same folder as html code where I only write path('input.js') only then it works. Do you know why could this happen?

Comment: @DevangMukherjee you should check relative vs absolute paths. I can't really give you the correct path without knowing the file structure.

Answer (score 2):

Check input.js present in /public/utils/input.js path or not.